# Win XP and auto login

Tags: windows, windows-xp, login

How to enforce autologin not just first time when computer boots, but even if user click logoff.

So when user clicks logoff, he is imidiatly loged back.

Comment: I saw this on some embeded winXP box. When you powerd on the computer you get logged directly into user account. When you cklicked log off you have been logged of and the imidiatly loged in back again.
For accessing the administrator account you have had to press and hold shift key and then click logof.
This way you get the normal windows login dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[On Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) and [Windows 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737):

Under **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`** add the following values (of type *REG_SZ*):

1. `DefaultUserName` – the user name
2. `DefaultPassword` – the password to use
3. `AutoAdminLogon` – `1` to enable automatic logon
4. **`ForceAutoLogon`** – **`1`** to enforce automatic logon when the user logs out

Note that the key and all of its values, including `DefaultPassword`, are readable by authenticated users both locally and through Remote Registry:

Answer (score 1):

Use a GPO to remove the user's ability to log off.

Problem solved.

Comment: This is not the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with out using GPO by using tweakui...Another way the problem is solved.

Comment: This is not the desired solution.

Comment: @Primoz: It would be more helpful if your comments _explained_ why the solution is undesired.